# How to get CSS media queries for images to work on AMP posts?

Tags: css, wordpress, amp-html

For most of my blog posts I need to use two different images for desktop vs mobile.
Sometimes it's because of placement issues but it's mostly for promoting my products. I would like to have a wider image on desktop between paragraphs, but a more square shaped image for mobile in the same place so it isn't all squished and hard to read the text in the image.

I have done this using @media queries in my custom CSS template in my WordPress theme (Sprout), and it works fine usually - but not on my amp pages.

```
@media (min-width: 980px) {
    img.beat-pcos-10-week-program-ad-mobile.aligncenter {
    display: none;
}
}
@media (max-width: 980px) {
    img.beat-pcos-10-week-program-ad-desktop.aligncenter {
    display: none;
}
}
```

For example:

http://www.smartfertilitychoices.com/5-sugar-hacks-dessert-pcos/ 
 vs
http://www.smartfertilitychoices.com/5-sugar-hacks-dessert-pcos/amp/

Towards the bottom of the blog post, there is an image promoting my 10 Week Program and using the code above, it shows a different image depending on browser width on the regular post, but not the AMP post.

Is there a way to hide the desktop version of the image on my AMP posts?

Thanks!

Comment: Media queries [are supported](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/responsive/responsive_design#creating-a-responsive-layout) - have you tried debugging to see what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd strongly advice against using CSS media queries to show or hide images based on device dimensions (for AMP and non-AMP pages). The problem is: even if an image is hidden via `display: none` it's still going to be downloaded. This means in your case the user will always have to download both versions of your image which is a waste of bandwidth.

Here are two possible approaches to avoid this for AMP and non-AMP pages:

**Non-AMP**

For non-AMP pages you can use the `picture` element. It allows you to specify different sources for different device dimensions. The browser will only download the image that fits the current device:

```
<picture>
 <source srcset="wide.png" media="(min-width: 980px)">
 <img src="square.jpg" alt="...">
</picture>
```

**AMP**

AMP doesn't support the picture element, but you can replicate the behavior using [element media queries](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/responsive/control_layout#element-media-queries):

```
<amp-img
    media="(max-width: 980px)"
    src="square.jpg"
    width=400
    height=400
    layout="responsive">
</amp-img>
<amp-img
    media="(min-width: 980px)"
    src="wide.jpg"
    width=1280
    height=768
    layout="responsive">
</amp-img>
```

This will also ensure that only one image will be downloaded.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be working so far with images that sit in the same place for mobile and desktop. I've got some images that will sit a bit higher up on desktop than mobile though, for example an image I want to the right of a piece of text is placed at the start of that paragraph, but on mobile I want the image to appear after the paragraph.
Is it possible to hide/show images altogether for certain widths using the <picture> element? I'm not great at this stuff sorry!

Comment: Hi, this no longer is working... it seems the recent Wordpress update now strips out both the `picture` and `amp-img` elements upon updating the blog posts to something like this: `<div class="hidden-sm hidden-xs">
<img src="IMG-URL" class="alignright" alt="ALT-TEXT" width="390" height="325"></div>` Which still works for the regular blog post, but the div class to hide/show based on device size doesn't work for amp pages.. Any idea of where to go to? I have posted another thread in the forum, as well as contacted AMPforWP (plugin I use). Just reaching out here in case you can help! thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

`img` tags are not allowed directly in AMP pages; `amp-img` tags are used instead. So assuming that your `img` tags are being converted to `amp-img` tags, you can try to apply your media queries to `amp-img` with class `beat-pcos-10-week-program-ad-mobile` instead of `img`. Or better yet, apply your media queries to both `amp-img` and `img` tags with the `beat-pcos-10-week-program-ad-mobile` class (this way it will work for both AMP and non-AMP pages).

So:

```
@media (min-width: 980px) {
    img.beat-pcos-10-week-program-ad-mobile.aligncenter,
    amp-img.beat-pcos-10-week-program-ad-mobile.aligncenter {
        display: none;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 980px) {
    img.beat-pcos-10-week-program-ad-desktop.aligncenter,
    amp-img.beat-pcos-10-week-program-ad-desktop.aligncenter {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Looking at your source code, you appear to be running AmpForWP, and you seem to be already using the [custom CSS editor](https://ampforwp.com/tutorials/article/how-to-change-font-style-in-amp/). The `beat-pcos-10-week-program-ad-mobile` class does not seem to be defined anywhere on your AMP page, so the solution is to post your CSS into AmpForWP's custom editor as well as your main desktop theme's one.